# How to access SharePoint site through Java

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, credentials

I want access my SharePoint site through Java. I use the SharePoint's webservice, but it needs credentials, and I don't know how to fill in the credentials in Java.

Below is some code in .Net:

```
WSLists.Lists wslists = new WSLists.Lists();                  
wslists.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("administrator", "pass@word1", "mosing");
```

Can someone give me some advice or some sample code? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The way sharepoint webservices perform actions from java, at least as my team and I found it, is it creates an instance of a webservice, binds a username and password to that instance, then that instance performs an action.

Below you'll see we bind a username and password to a ListSoap object, because we want to checkin or checkout a file.  The code below binds the username and password to a port.  Then, we can do something like port.checkOut(...).  Hope this makes sense for you.

```
public ListsSoap sharePointListsWebServiceAuth(){
     ListsSoap port = null;
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            try {
                ListsService service = new ListsService();
                port = service.getListsSoap();
                ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
                ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't authenticate: Invalid connection details given.");
        }
        return port;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this java api i've developed to communicate with sharepoint rest api. If it still a not full implementation but can solve most common actions you'll need. Also as its open source you can extend it to accomplish what you need.

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java

Hopes this helps